# How do I add custom functions to Sass (via Sass::Script::Functions)?

Tags: sass

I am using vanilla Sass (no Compass/SUZY/Bourbon/etc.) and I'm having trouble figuring out where to put my *.rb file.  I am not a Ruby programmer, but I did find a function someone else wrote that does what I need.  I've tried searching, but the results I've come up with are dead ends.

The official docs themselves offer no clues, only how to create a custom function:
http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#adding_custom_functions

```
sass styles.scss styles.css -r custom.rb
```

LoadError: no such file to load -- static/sass/modules/lib/custom.rb while trying this solution (despite being able to VI the file):
http://www.seancolombo.com/2010/07/28/how-to-make-and-use-a-custom-sass-function/

This is the closest SO question I could find, but I'm not using Compass or Rails so the solutions don't make any sense to me:
[How do I load extensions to the Sass::Script::Functions module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690372/how-do-i-load-extensions-to-the-sassscriptfunctions-module)

I would like to keep my custom functions within my modules directory (which contains my own custom Bootstrap library).  But if it has to go elsewhere, I can live with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following the instructions from your second link, but specify an absolute path to your ruby file. On my machine, it looks like SASS has issues finding the file if it's given a relative path.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work.  Is there maybe a better way of adding in custom functions?  The absolute path to my file is rather long.  More of a nuisance really, since I am running the command from a shell script anyway.

Comment: I agree, it is a nuisance! I'm guessing this is because there was a change in Ruby 1.9 that removed the current directory from the list of load paths, so you may want to submit a [bug report](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues) to the SASS developers. I don't know of any "better" way to include custom functions.

Comment: After further research `-r ./static/sass/modules/lib/custom.rb` will work, no need to use the absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 4, it's very simple. Create a sass.rb file in your config/initializer/ folder and put your module in there.

For example, take this random function: https://gist.github.com/chriseppstein/1561650

```
module Sass::Script::Functions
  def random(*args)
    #...buncha code
  end
end
```

Just stick that in config/initializers/sass.rb and you'll have access to it in any of your .scss/sass stylesheets like:

```
.greet{
  position: absolute;
  top: random(200px);
  left: random(200px);
  height: random(200px);
  width: random(200px);
  background-color: blue;

}
```