# Is it possible to implement `Lists` functions of Compass in plain vanilla Sass?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

The Lists functions in Compass is here:

https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/blob/stable/lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions/lists.rb

If someone has tried either success or fail…

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use Compass?  It seems silly to want the features of Compass, but not want to *use* Compass.

Comment: I want to get rid of a dependency to Compass.  You can call me silly if you like.

Comment: The cure is worse than the disease, my friend.  If you're running Sass via command line, you'll have to write in the path to your custom functions every time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356373/how-do-i-add-custom-functions-to-sass-via-sassscriptfunctions